# Difference between XmlElement and XmlElementAttribute in c# xml serialization

Tags: c#, xmlserializer

What is difference between XmlElement and XmlElementAttribute in c# xml serialization. I am facing an issue while xml serialization of an object.

Actually, I have 2 fields with the same name. 1 in Base class and other in child class and I need to set different element names for those to show in xml doc.

Comment: Please describe your specific problem, otherwise it's nearly impossible to provide an answer that helps you fix the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Well, It depends on your XML file structure. If the child element is a an xml tag, you should add XmlElement data annotation. If the property of your class is bound to an attribute related to the current node, then add an attribute data annotation.

```
[Serializable()]
public class Person
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("Name")]
    public string Name{ get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("Phone")]
    public int Phone { get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("Address ")]
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

In this case your xml structure should like this:

```
  <person>
        <name>...</name>
        <phone>...</phone>
        <address>...</address>
  </person>
```

Now if the properties represents child attributes, it will be like this:

```
<person name='...' phone='...' address='...'></person>
```

Comment: I already have tried this but didn't worked.got exception: There was an error reflecting type:
Use XmlElementAttribute or XmlAttributeAttribute to specify a new name.

Comment: @Hamdi Baligh How do you add an attribute to Element <name>?